# Thymeleaf display element as active when using layout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, navigationbar

I wanted to display navigation element as active (class nav-item active) when that element is clicked and the other elements with the non active class (nav-item). I am also using Thymeleaf layouts.

In the controller i have following code

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
public String getLoginPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("activeLink", "Login");
    return "login";
}
```

In the layout.html file (this file contains common header and footer for all pages), i have following code

```
    <nav th:replace="navigation.html :: navibar(activeLink=${activeLink})"></nav>
```

In the navigation.html (this file only has navigation related code), i have code similar to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" th:fragment="navibar(activeLink)">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/title">Title</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li th:class="${#strings.equals(activeLink, 'Home')} ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li th:class="${#strings.equals(activeLink, 'Register')} ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Register</a></li>
        <li th:class="${#strings.equals(activeLink, 'Login')} ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'" sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/login}">Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item active" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the template returned by the controller (login), I do not have any navigation links specific code.

The above code is working, but is there a better simpler way to active navigation items?
Also, if I use flash attributes

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("activeLink", "Register");
```

in the controller, then the functionality doesn't work

Comment: You could pass the activeLink where you include the navigation template. Then you don't have to add it to the model

Comment: that is a good alternative, thank you. I am able to add a layout fragment in each of the templates, which would call the nagivation.html :: navibar(). This avoids going through the controller

Comment: Yes. I would add this as the answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding the activeLink to the model you can pass the activeLink when you include the fragment.

Like:

```
<div th:replace="nagivation :: navibar('Login')"></div>
```

Btw. you can remove the .html after the layout name.